# Twilio simulring with callerID attribute

Tags: api, callback, twilio, phone-call

I'm trying to achieve the following workflow:

- Call number #1
- If no answer, call number #2
- If no answer, record voicemail with custom mp3

Previously, using the forward Twimlet I was able to specify the caller ID, which then came through on the call forward caller ID as my twilio number. Now though, using "find me" or "simulring" the initial caller's ID is shown and not my twilio number.

Is there any way to acheive a call forward, across multiple numbers, which can specify a caller ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

That seems to just be a limitation of the Simulring and Find Me twimlets.

You could achieve the same as the Find Me twimlet with multiple uses of the original Forward twimlet. You would do so as follows:

- Set up a Forward twimlet for number #2 with a FailUrl that points to the voicemail twimlet you are using
- Set up a Forward twimlet for number #1 with the FailUrl that points to number #2's Forward twimlet

You can set CalledIds on each of the Forward twimlets and this will effectively be the same behaviour as the Find Me twimlet, just with a little extra work, but the working CallerID.